# Why wont [NSTextStorage appendAttributedString: ] accept my NSAttributedString's attributes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to put text with a specific font and color into an NSTextView. I can put the text in just fine, but it loses my attributes:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSFont fontWithName:@"Monaco" size:10], @"NSFontAttributeName",
    [NSColor blueColor],                     @"NSForegroundColorAttributeName",
    nil];
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:someNSString
                                                             attributes: dict];
[someNSTextStorage appendAttributedString:string];
```

I've read the all the relevant class references (NSTextView, NSTextStorage, NSAttributedString, etc...) and I still don't know why it doesn't work as I expect.

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: I'm still not sure where the problem lies, but I can work around it by using `[storage setForegroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];` and `[storage setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Monaco" size:10]];`
after appendAttributedString:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your problem: You've enclosed `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` in quotes. So instead of a macro you're passing an NSString literal. Same goes for your `NSFontAttributeName` as well. Get rid of those and you're set.